# JavaFX Controller loading

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I came across some very strange behaviour a couple of times every time forgetting the trick.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/window.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
GuiController controller = loader.getController();
```

Now the `controller` is not null.

However, after I do this...

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/window.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("view/window.fxml"));
GuiController controller = loader.getController();
```

The `controller` is now `null`.

I understand that the `loader` somehow looses his grip on location? I would very much appreciate somebody telling me that this is an expected behaviour and explain me why.

Please note that is looked quite a bit after post concerning this problem found nothing, and discovered the solution only after 2h of experimentation, so please don't link me up with similar looking questions.

Comment: You presumably mean `loader`, not `fxmlLoader` in both calls to `setLocation(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` method [`load(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) is a `static` method. So your second code block is equivalent to (compiles to)

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
// I assume you mean loader, not fxmlLoader, in the next line:
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/window.fxml"));
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/window.fxml"));
GuiController controller = loader.getController();
```

In other words, you never invoke `load(...)` on `loader`: hence `loader` never parses the FXML and never instantiates the controller.

In your first code block, you invoke the no-arg [`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) method, which is an instance method.

Comment: Haven't noticed the `static` keyword in the documentation. Thank you very much. :) Lost quite a lot of my evening for that.

Comment: For some reason I had my warning suppressed for this class... After switching them back on it performed as you said it would. Thanks.

Comment: Most IDEs will give you a warning if you call a static method from a reference.